# problem with php code not working. or i am doing something wrong

Tags: php, obfuscation

I am trying to have this php code return the output of the second file.

File 1

```
<?
$fin=fopen(__FILE__,'rb');
fread($fin,0x47a);
$code=base64_decode(strtr(fread($fin,0x17c),
    'EnteryouwkhRHYKNWOUTAaBbCcDdFfGgIiJjLlMmPpQqSsVvXxZz0123456789+/=',
    'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789+/'));
eval($code);
?>
```

Second File.

```
kr9NHenNHenNHe1zfukgFMaXdoyjcUImb19oUAxyb18mRtwmwJ4LT09NHr8XTzEXRJwmwJXLT09NHeEXHr8XhtONT08XHeEXHr8Pkr8XTzEXT08XHtILTzEXHr8XTzEXRtONTzEXTzEXHeEpRtfydmOlFmlvfbfqDykwBAsKa09aaryiWMkeC0OLOMcuc0lpUMpHdr1sAunOFaYzamcCGyp6HerZHzW1YjF4KUSvNUFSk0ytW0OyOLfwUApRTr1KT1nOAlYAaacbBylDCBkjcoaMc2ipDMsSdB5vFuyZF3O1fmf4GbPXHTwzYeA2YzI5hZ8mhULpK2cjdo9zcUILTzEXHr8XTzEXhTslfMyShtONTzEXTzEXTzEpKX==tmklFbapFMagd25jcUEPwtwVRJ9jd25MDBFVFoiXwJLIKXppcJEPwolVfucidtEPwtOgA0aTA0lNTlSJdo9mDB5gCBOsDB5gDBWJbUEpwe09weEIhWp7tMilCBOlFJEPwtkSd2YifolvdjppdMOlGt5XDuEJhUE7tMa4DbWIhtEpweShgWpZcby1Dbklb29VC2AIhtEJRJ4vC2xiF3YlFZ9sDbYjRMc1dMHVFoiXwJLIKXpZcby1Dbklb29VC2AIhtEJRJ4vC2xiF3YlFZ9sCB5pFuaSCbOlRmnPFtwpweShkoOiforINUnVcbFIOoy0CA1idMlXfBxifo9ZwtIIhUE7tJO0DbOScUE9wtOLCbOiRT5zcBxlC3WIhtEJA2l0cA1idMymcbwJRtwQwJxiFmkiGUEPwtkTDbOlaMyZDByJdoAJNT4JA2l0cA5idBAJhUEpweShkuOpfoxlwe0IkuOpfoxlBznfweSh
```

Please help me understand what i am doing wrong and how i can make File 1 parse the data in file 2.

Thanks

Comment: as far as i can see you open file1 in file1 and try to parse it.

Comment: ya it looks like that but i must be missing something. because its not working.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use `__FILE__` in the `fopen()` call -- use the name of the second file.  The obfuscated File 1 looks to have some tight tolerances given its reads of 0x47a and 0x17c bytes.

File 1 opens itself, reads the first 0x47a bytes, reads the next 0x17c bytes, tries to match the `'Enter you...` string, and the `'ABCDEF...` string is interpreted as `TRUE` so `strstr` is going to return everything BEFORE the matching string.

It then tries to base64 decode that (offset 0x47a to the start of "Enter you...") and evaluate it as code.

Based on that description, I'd say the code in File 1 has been modified from its original form, since I can't see it as working properly.  The file offsets don't make sense, and the matching doesn't make sense either.